# Implementing Kerberos Authentication on Linux servers using script

Tags: linux, ldap, authentication, kerberos, pam

My client wants to implement Kerberos Authentication on multiple Oracle Linux Boxes. Do they need to be done manually or can I implement on all of them using any script? Is there any way to script this and enable the authentication on all the servers at the same time?

Comment: Did you look at FreeIPA?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the requirement, but it seems to me that scripting might be the wrong approach.
If they are using "Oracle Linux Boxes" we can assume that it will be a kind of RHEL based system, likely a version 7.

Kerberos is often used for authentication only, and most of the time combined with a directory (e.g. active directory, ldap, ...).

FreeIPA can be a solution to get that done, but often sssd only configured appropriately can be sufficient. FreeIPA offers deeper system integration and many interesting features, but is also more complex.

Since the requirement was not very clear, it is essential to state that the answer is related to Linux System integration, mainly PAM.

Comment: Just seen that I missed to paste the documentation link I had intended to submit: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system-level_authentication_guide/configuring_domains